# Span element not showing

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to create a pagination algorithm. The problem I am facing is that once I set the span element's `innerText` to an empty string in the `showData` function, it wont show, it just disappears.

Maybe it's because I'm using `innerText`, should I use `textContent` or `innerHTML`?

```
var number = 1;
var maxPost = 10;
var classname;

defaultPrint();
Pagination();

function defaultPrint() {
  for (let i = 0; i < maxPost; i++) {
    document.getElementById("span").append(contacts[i]);
    document.getElementById("span").append(" ");
  }
}

function Pagination() {
  for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      let id = e.target.id;
      let maxRange = maxPost * id;
      let minRange = maxRange - maxPost;
      showData(minRange, maxRange);
    });
  }
}

function showData(minRange, maxRange) {
  document.getElementById("span").innerText = "";
  for (let i = minRange; i < maxRange; i++) {
    if (contacts[i] !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("span").append(contacts[i]);
      document.getElementById("span").append(" ");
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("getData").addEventListener("click", function () {
  maxPost = parseInt(document.getElementById("data").value);

  if (maxPost > 0) {
    number = 1;

    Pagination();
    defaultPrint();
  }
});
```

Comment: Can you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ?

Comment: I have reduced the code. Please check now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimal reproductif example.
I've also corrected it :
`let maxRange = maxPost * id;` become `let maxRange = maxPost * parseInt(id);`

```js
var contacts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var number = 1;
var maxPost = 3;
var classname;

function createButton(number) {
  var x = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var t = document.createTextNode(number);
  x.appendChild(t);
  x.id = number;
  x.className = "Button";

  document.body.appendChild(x);
}

function TotalButtons() {
  if (contacts.length > maxPost) {
    for (let i = 0; i < contacts.length; i = i + maxPost) {
      createButton(number);
      number++;
    }
  } else {
    createButton(number);
    number++;
  }
  classname = document.getElementsByClassName("Button");
}

function RemoveButtons() {
  for (let a = 1; a < number; a++) {
    document.getElementById(a).remove();
  }
}

TotalButtons();
defaultPrint();
Pagination();

//var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("Button");
function defaultPrint() {
  document.getElementById("span").textContent = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < maxPost; i++) {
    document.getElementById("span").append(contacts[i]);
    document.getElementById("span").append(" ");
  }
}

function Pagination() {
  for (let i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      let id = e.target.id;
      let maxRange = maxPost * parseInt(id);
      let minRange = maxRange - maxPost;
      showData(minRange, maxRange);
    });
  }
}

function showData(minRange, maxRange) {
  document.getElementById("span").textContent = "";
  for (let i = minRange; i < maxRange; i++) {
    if (contacts[i] !== undefined) {
      document.getElementById("span").append(contacts[i]);
      document.getElementById("span").append(" ");
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
}

document.getElementById("getData").addEventListener("click", function () {
  maxPost = parseInt(document.getElementById("data").value);

  if (maxPost > 0) {
    RemoveButtons();
    number = 1;
    TotalButtons();
    Pagination();
    defaultPrint();
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="getData" role="button">Load</button>
<div id="span"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="data" value="3">
```

Comment: The problem is once I make the innerText of span element to emtpy string " ".
It does not appear again after I set a value to it again after setting it to empty string.